# Spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators on a complex space

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading [Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra](http://uap.unnes.ac.id/ebook/mathematics%20ebook/Algebra/Linear%20Algebra,%202nd%20ed%20-%20Kenneth%20Hoffman,%20Ray%20Kunze,%201971.pdf) and on page 335 they prove the spectral theorem:

[image]

My question is really simple, I just want to make sure there is no catch here. Can I say this theorem is true for self-adjoint operator on a *complex* space $V$? Since the theorems they used to prove this one are true for a general vector space (real or complex). See on page 314:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because every self-adjoint linear operator is normal.